# Drag and drop between two React components

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am trying to create a React app where I can drag and drop a DOM element from a "palette" of available DOM elements into a blank "canvas" area in the second component. The available elements appear as an unordered list of React components the user can use to build a customized website. (I am basically trying to copy Wix.)

I am just learning so I am copying heavily -- I don't really understand the limitations of HTML5 Drag N Drop. Maybe it doesn't work at all between React components.

If I were trying to drag and drop from Component A into Component A, it would be easy -- HTML5 can do that and I've read about it. But I don't know how to adapt it to drag and drop from Component A into Component B.

I've tried copying the `onDrop` function, "drop()", from Component A to Component B but that didn't work.

Maybe I need a library like "react-beautiful-dnd" to accomplish this?

Here is my code as it is:

Component A:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Palette extends Component {
    dragStartHandler = event => {
        event.dataTransfer.setData("text/plain", event.target.id); // returns undefined ??
        console.log(event);
    };

    dragendHandler = event => {};

    dragEndHandler = event => {
        console.log("Ended drag");
    };

    dragStart = event => {
        event.dataTransfer.setData("text", event.target.id);
        console.log("Drag started");
    };

    drop = event => {
        if (event.target.id) {
            event.dataTransfer.getData("text");
            event.dataTransfer.clearData();
        }
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="palette-container">
                <h3>Your Palette</h3>
                <ul>
                    <li
                        id="header"
                        draggable="true"
                        onDrop={this.drop}
                        onDragStart={this.dragStartHandler}
                        onDragOver={event => event.preventDefault()}
                        onDragEnd={this.dragEndHandler}
                    >
                        Header
                    </li>
                    <li>Second component I wish to drop</li>

                </ul>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Palette;
```

Component B looks approximately like Component A (because I don't know what else to write).

Here is what I imagine a fully functional example would involve. Something in the palette component allows the canvas component to know when its time to create a new DOM element.

Palette:

```
class Palette extends Component {
    fireCreateComponent = (elementType) => {
        createComponent(elementType);
    }

render() {
        return (
            <div className="palette-container">
                <h3>Your Palette</h3>
                <ul>
                    <li
                        id="header"
                        draggable="true"
                        onDragStart={this.fireCreateComponent()}
                    >
                        Draggable Header
                    </li>
                    <li
                        id="headline"
                        draggable="true"
                        onDragStart={this.fireCreateComponent()}
                    >
                        Draggable Headline
                    </li>
                    <li
                        id="text-area"
                        draggable="true"
                        onDragStart={this.fireCreateComponent()}
                    >
                        Draggable Text Area
                    </li>
                    // and so on to create different components in the Canvas section
                </ul>
            </div>
        );
    }
```

Canvas:

```
class Canvas extends Component {
    createComponent = (componentType, props) => {
        React.createElement(<componentType props={props}/>)

render() {
        return (
            <div className="canvas-container">
                <h3>Drag Elements Here</h3>
                <div className="canvas">
                    <ul>
                        <li>Empty Space 1</li>
                        <div
                            onDrop={this.createComponent}
                        >
                            {" "}
                        </div>
                        <li>Empty Space 2</li>
                        <div
                            onDrop={this.createComponent}
                        >
                            {" "}
                        </div>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
```

Comment: Hey did u try this : [drag and drop ](https://react-dnd.github.io/react-dnd/about)?

Comment: I will check it out! Thanks. I've been resisting going to libraries -- stubbornly, I'd like to use plain HTML5 and javascript

Comment: when It comes to drag and drop Its better u use library, its not simple as u think, in vanilla javascript or jquery we use JquerryUI , its perfect, https://jqueryui.com/draggable/

Comment: Does the jQuery option work with react?

Comment: jQuery works with react but don't go in that direction, react-dnd is a perfect library for handling drag-drop functionalities in ReactJS

Comment: @RolyPoly reatc is just a library like jquery in javascript , jquery UI works perfect too , but as Aldrin said that is not the righ way to do it , so go with react-dnd